# Does Ctypes Structures and POINTERS automatically free the memory when the Python object is deleted?

Tags: python, ctypes

When using Python CTypes there are the Structures, that allow you to clone c-structures on the Python side, and the POINTERS objects that create a sofisticated Python Object from a memory address value and can be used to pass objects by reference back and forth C code.

What I could not find on the documentation or elsewhere is what happens when a Python object containing a Structure class that was de-referenced from a returning pointer from C Code (that is - the C function alocated memory for the structure) is itself deleted.  Is the memory for the original C structure freed? If not how to do it?

Furthermore -- what if the Structure contains Pointers itself, to other data that was also allocated by the C function? Does the deletion of the Structure object frees the Pointers onits members? (I doubt so) Else - -how to do it? Trying to call the system "free" from Python for the Pointers in the Structure is crashing Python for me.

In other words, I have this structure filled up by a c Function call:

```
class PIX(ctypes.Structure):
    """Comments not generated
    """
    _fields_ = [
        ("w", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("h", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("d", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("wpl", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("refcount", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("xres", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("yres", ctypes.c_uint32),
        ("informat", ctypes.c_int32),
        ("text", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)),
        ("colormap", ctypes.POINTER(PIXCOLORMAP)),
        ("data", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_uint32))
    ]
```

And I want to free the memory it is using up from Python code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The memory is not freed, because Python has no idea if or how it should be freed.  Compare these two functions:

```
void testfunc1(PIX *pix)
{
    static char staticBuffer[256] = "static memory";
    pix->text = staticBuffer;
}

void testfunc2(PIX *pix)
{
    pix->text = (char *)malloc(32);
    strcpy(pix->text, "dynamic memory");
}
```

Used like this:

```
pix1, pix2 = PIX(), PIX()
mylib.testfunc1(ctypes.byref(pix1))
mylib.testfunc2(ctypes.byref(pix2))
```

And then at some point, `pix1` and `pix2` go out of scope.  When that happens, nothing happens to the inner pointers—if they pointed to dynamic memory (as is the case here with `pix2` but *not* `pix1`), you are responsible for freeing it.

The proper way to solve this problem is, if you allocate dynamic memory in your C code, you should provide a corresponding function that deallocates that memory.  For example:

```
void freepix(PIX *pix)
{
    free(pix->text);
}


pix2 = PIX()
mylib.testfunc2(ctypes.byref(pix2))
...
mylib.freepix(ctypes.byref(pix2))
```