# ctypes receiving pointer and memory management

Tags: python, c, pointers, memory-management

I have created C method, which is returning const char * from method as a result:

```
const char * extractDescriptor (int descriptorType, const char * imgURL, const char ** params);
```

Now in Python I receive pointer and decode that information to a string.

```
lib.extractDescriptor.restype  = c_char_p
result = lib.extractDescriptor(descriptorType, imgPath, parameters)
result_decoded = c_char_p(result).value.decode("utf-8");
```

How it comes to memory management problem? Should I make copy of value and create another method to free that pointer (which was created in C) or it is being released automaticly by Python?

In definition itself of extractDescriptor it returns
result of that function:

```
const char * message(std::string xml) {
    char * msg = new char[xml.size() + 1];
    strcpy(msg, xml.c_str());
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: It's terminology but there are no methods in [tag:c], because it's not an object oriented language. They are called *functions*. And it depends, could you post the definition of `extractDescriptor()`?

Comment: I've asked basically the same a couple years ago - and the answer I've been given is quite complete. TL,TR; if you alocate memory in C, you should have a C call to dealocate it. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551436/does-ctypes-structures-and-pointers-automatically-free-the-memory-when-the-pytho